# Does the write function serialize an object using ASCII in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization, binary

Suppose we write an object to a binary as follows:

```
file.write((char*) &object, sizeof(object))
```

Suppose the object has private member data of character arrays and integer types (no `std::string`)

Question: Does the `write` function write the object's attributes to ASCII? In particular, are the object's private member variables written as ASCII? Can someone specify exactly what this function does?

Comment: It just spits out bytes.  Those bytes might match ascii encodings.  Or they don't, the world does not speak ascii or pointer.  Maybe you can read them back properly.  Or you don't, depends, don't send it too far away.

Comment: That `write` will write out all the data contained in `object`, including pointers to virtual tables. Also, you could easily try this and then look at the resulting file in a hex-dump to see what's actually written.

Comment: Oh and I should emphasize that the point about virtual table pointer being written is kind of important, because it means you can never really read the object using a simple single `read` call (corresponding to the simple single `write` call used to write the object). Proper, working serialization is not easy, use an existing library to handle it and all crazy corner-cases.

Answer (score 3):

`write()` writes the individual bytes as is. Whatever they have, that's what gets written. That's pretty much the end of the story.

So, if your object contains a character array that contains text that's encoded in `ASCII`, that's what it gets written. If the same character array contains text that's encoded in Klingon, you'll get Klingon in your file, etc... What you see is what you get.

Answer (score 1):

If the stream is opened as `binary` mode, there will be no translations applied to the data.

> Does the write function write the object's attributes to ASCII?

The `binary` mode of the stream says no conversions.  What's in memory is written directly to the stream, no alterations.

> In particular, are the object's private member variables written as ASCII?

The entire object is written, regardless of scope (public, private or protected).  The code is not written to the stream.

> Can someone specify exactly what this function does?

Exactly:  The function writes the given quantity of values in memory at the given address to the stream.

Thus, all the data of the object (including padding) will be written to the stream matching the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your object's binary representation under two conditions:

- `is_trivial<decltype(object)>::value` is true
- the file stream was opend in `ios::binary` mode

So non trivial types such as strings or other containers won't work, because their state can't be restored from a binary representation (missing memory allocations).

`write()` will write all content of the object as binary data.  If the data is ascii, it will be written in ascii, but no conversion takes palce.  If you want to write ascii, you have to handcraft the write with the standard stream inserter `<<`